# Checking if a value exists in a column. CountIf or Autofilter->If filtered range is Not Nothing

Tags: excel, vba

Which is more efficient for 50k rows of data?

1. Using CountIf to the whole columne ("A:A") and checking if a value exists then proceed with the code.
2. Using Autofilter with a criteria, if the produced range is not nothing then proceed with the code.

```
        With Worksheets("Raw")
            project_name_counter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A:A"), str_project_name)
        End With

        If project_name_counter > 0 Then

            With rng_raw
                    .AutoFilter 1, project_name
            End With
            ' code goes here
```

VERSUS

```
        With rng_raw
             .AutoFilter 1, str_project_name
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
            Set rng_filtered_raw = ws_raw.Range("J3", ws_raw.Cells(long_last_row_of_raw, 16)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng_filtered_raw Is Nothing Then
        ' code code here
```

I am actually looking for some insights and not sarcastic answers. Thank you.

Comment: Btw: `Vlookup` is also an option

Comment: Well, yes I can test, but would like to ask you guys the downside of using the first one and the downside of using the second one. So my question is not just about which would be faster but on the what is going on behind the background for each option and what do you think is the better way?

Comment: I can't offer insights but logic would suggest that applying a filter should be slower than a simple COUNTIF. If your aim to just know if a value exists you should also consider VBA's 'Find' method. Applying logic here as well, 'Find' may be a little slower than COUNTIF because it can look for formats as well but it's native to VBA as opposed to COUNTIF which is borrowed from Excel, and it stops at the first match while COUNTIF must always work to the end.

Comment: @Variatus Thank you. I will check out FIND.

Comment: And Vlookup I guess, so it will be like COUNTIF vs VLOOKUP vs FIND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Match vs CountIf vs Find feat. MicroTimer

I've done some research using `MicroTimer` written by [Charles Williams](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/4025136) which I found in the article [Finding Excel VBA Bottlenecks](https://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2014/january/com-2014-iss50/finding-excel-vba-bottlenecks).

**Description**

Sorry for the results being in the comments of the code, but it took me a while to create the following setup:

- `fillColumns`    - fills the range defined by `Cols` with the string defined by `FillString`.
- `TestAll`        - runs all four tests.
- `countFillChars` - counts the number of characters in `FillString`.
- `saveBook`       - saves the workbook.
- `TestWFMatch`    - tests the `WorksheetFunction` version of `Match`.
- `TestWFMatch`    - tests the `Application` version of `Match`.
- `TestCountIf`    - tests the `WorksheetFunction` version of `CountIf`.
- `TestFind`       - tests the `Find Method`.
- `MicroTimer`     - 'measures' the time needed to finish a test.

The results show the times passed in seconds. All tests except the test using the matched result in the first cell are all done on data where there is no match. The functions just 'loop through the cells' of 10 columns filled with the same string and 'do their job'. Hence one can conclude that the testing has just 'scratched' the surface.

**Conclusion**

The obvious (to me, not so scientific) conclusions of these tests are the following:

- When `Match` is used, it automatically stops when a match is found,
  while `CountIf` has to count to the end of the range. Therefore `Match`
  should be faster but it cannot count. `Find` (one of my favorites) doesn't come even close, 
  but it can do a ton of other stuff.
- I've used the same beginnings of the string on purpose, which showed
  me that as more matches of the characters there are the slower the
  functions get, something like:

  - '`This`' - that's not even close it has 4 characters (especially `Match`).
  - '`This string cont`' - getting closer (`CountIf` is already suffering, `Match` is staying fast.)
  - This looks to me like the functions are first counting the number of
    characters and only then checking if they are the same.
  - But the shocker is when the first character is different. Then
    `CountIf` 'springs to life beating' even `Match` at the same number of
    characters where it was only tested.

There are many more conclusions to be drawn and tests to be performed. The tools are here, the rest is up to you. Are you willing? Start with a test for `AutoFilter` which I regretfully did not include here.

**Remarks:**

The `14.5s` against the `0.0004s` when there is a match should not confuse you because it's an extreme: `Match` has 10 times found a match in the first cell, while `CountIf` 10 times counts over a million matches.

**The Code**

Put the code into a module. You just have to have `Sheet1` (CodeName).

```
Option Explicit

' saveBook 12-15s if filled

' Fill String                     WFCountIf  WFMatch    Match  Find    FillC
' This                                  3.0   0.4      0.4      4.5      4.5
' This str                              4.7   0.4      0.4      4.5      4.7
' This string cont                      9.0   0.4      0.4      4.5      5.0
' This string contains 32c             11.5   0.4      0.4      4.5      5.2
' This string contains 32 chars!!!     14.5   0.0005   0.0007   0.001    5.5
' This string contains 32 chars!!.     14.5  14.5     14.5     19.0      5.5
' This string contained 32 chars! I added some more to make it 64.
'                                      11.0  11.0     11.0     72.0      6.4
' 32chars contained in this string      1.8   2.0      2.0      6.5      5.5

Private Const FillString As String = "32chars contained in this string"
Private Const Srch As String = "This string contains 32 chars!!!"
Private Const Cols As String = "A:J"
Private Const UB As Long = 9
Private i As Long
Private tStart As Double
Private tEnd As Double

Sub fillColumns()
    tStart = MicroTimer
        Sheet1.Columns(Cols).Value = FillString
    Debug.Print MicroTimer - tStart
End Sub

Sub TestAll()
    TestWFMatch
    TestMatch
    TestWFCountIf
    TestFind
End Sub

Sub countFillChars()
    Debug.Print Len(FillString)
End Sub

Sub saveBook()
    tStart = MicroTimer
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    Debug.Print MicroTimer - tStart
End Sub

Sub TestWFMatch()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim Result(UB) As Boolean
    Dim FResult As Long

    tStart = MicroTimer
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            For i = 1 To 10
                On Error Resume Next
                    FResult = _
                      .Match(Srch, ws.Range(Cols).Columns(i), 0)
                    Result(i - 1) = Err.Number = 0
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next i
        End With
    tEnd = MicroTimer - tStart

    Debug.Print String(10, "-") & vbCrLf & tEnd * 1000
    For i = 0 To 9: Debug.Print Result(i): Next

End Sub

Sub TestMatch()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim Result(UB) As Boolean

    tStart = MicroTimer
        With Application
            For i = 1 To 10
                Result(i - 1) = _
                  Not IsError(.Match(Srch, ws.Range(Cols).Columns(i), 0))
            Next i
        End With
    tEnd = MicroTimer - tStart

    Debug.Print String(10, "-") & vbCrLf & tEnd * 1000
    For i = 0 To 9: Debug.Print Result(i): Next

End Sub

Sub TestWFCountIf()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim Result(UB) As Boolean

    tStart = MicroTimer
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            For i = 1 To 10
                Result(i - 1) = _
                  .CountIf(ws.Range(Cols).Columns(i), Srch) > 0
            Next i
        End With
    tEnd = MicroTimer - tStart

    Debug.Print String(10, "-") & vbCrLf & tEnd * 1000
    For i = 0 To UB: Debug.Print Result(i): Next

End Sub

Sub TestFind()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim Result(UB) As Boolean

    tStart = MicroTimer
        With Application
            For i = 1 To 10
                Result(i - 1) = _
                  Not ws.Columns(i).Find(What:=Srch, After:=ws.Cells( _
                    ws.Rows.Count, i), LookIn:=xlFormulas) Is Nothing
            Next i
        End With
    tEnd = MicroTimer - tStart

    Debug.Print String(10, "-") & vbCrLf & tEnd * 1000
    For i = 0 To 9: Debug.Print Result(i): Next

End Sub


'START ****************************************************************** START'
Private Declare Function getFrequency Lib "Kernel32" _
        Alias "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "Kernel32" _
        Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long
'******************************************************************************'
' Purpose:      Returns processor time. Used to determine small time intervals '
'               passed between places in code.                                 '
' Returns:      Processor time.                                                '
' Precedents:   getFrequency, getTickCount                                     '
'******************************************************************************'
Function MicroTimer() As Double
' Returns seconds.
    Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
    Static cyFrequency As Currency
    MicroTimer = 0
' Get frequency.
    If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency
' Get ticks.
    getTickCount cyTicks1
' Seconds
    If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency
End Function
'******************************************************************************'
' Example:                                                                     '
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Sub MicroTimerExample()
'    Dim dTime As Double
'    dTime = MicroTimer
'    Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To 1000000: Next
'    Debug.Print MicroTimer - dTime
'End Sub
'******************************************************************************'
' Source                                                                       '
'   Article                                                                    '
'     Title:    Excel 2010 Performance: Improving Calculation Performance
'     Link:     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/_
'               developer/office-2010/ff700515(v%3doffice.14)
'******************************************************************************'
' Found:        2018                                                           '
' Origin:       VBAddin.xlam                                                   '
'******************************************************************************'
```

Comment: VBasic2008 thank you very much. Your answer is really complete. The strings I need to use in my project are more like "This string cont" because they have this format "B-XXXX-XXXXX" with X replaced with numbers so I think I will be using WFMatch. And yes I am willing to make a test of my own, I just needed to know how to start and you showed me. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, Match is legacy right compared to WFMatch?

Comment: I will also test AutoFilter but I don't think it will beat Match or WFMatch.